# How to get unique numbers from two lists in dart?

Tags: list, dart

```
void main() {
  List<int> x = [1,4,3,6];
  List<int> y = [3,6,9,10,2];
  
  var List<int> output = [];

  print(output);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Unique numbers from List x and List y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly "unique numbers" mean in your context.
I guest "unique numbers" from list x an y mean the numbers which are in x or in y.
Example: `x = [1, 2, 3]`, `y = [2, 3, 4]`, the output is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
or `x = [3, 4, 5]` and `y = [5, 6, 7]` => `ouput = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`
If this is the result you want to archive, you can consider following code:

```dart
void main() {
    List<int> x = [1,4,3,6];
    List<int> y = [3,6,9,10,2];
    List<int> output = x.toSet().union(y.toSet()).toList();
    print(output);
}
```

output:

```
[1, 4, 3, 6, 9, 10, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

I am javascript developer but that would help you

`Var uniqueArray =list1.filter(function(obj){return list2.indexOf(obj)== -1;})`